# What is the original appearance and sound of the Nicene Creed?

Tags: resource-request, greek, nicene-creed

There are numerous places on line where one can see the modern Greek text of the creed and hear it read.  I would like to know how differently the original 4th century text would appear in a contemporary manuscript, and how differently it would sound if verbalised by one of the original authors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about linguistics rather than about Christianity.

Comment: I am wondering if you have any particular possibilities in mind, such as whether the Creed as originally written had a lyrical, rythmic or rhyming quality to it? Have u any theory or reading to this effect?  Obviously there are no recordings. However I have heard that American accents are closer to Tudor/Jacobean English than modern British accents; and we know this because Shakespeare, other poetry, the King James Bible and Prayer Book often sound better in American. I just wonder if this is what you are looking for in the Nicene Creed?

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I am neither linguist or a Greek.

Since [Koine Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koine_Greek) was used in that era, you could compare it with the current language rules.

There are two versions: [Creed of 325](http://www.earlychurchtexts.com/public/creed_of_nicaea_325.htm)
and [Constantinople Creed of 381](http://www.earlychurchtexts.com/public/nicene_creed.htm)
so you are probably looking for original version.

Original (325) Greek version:

> Πιστεύομεν εἰς ἕνα Θεὸν Πατέρα παντοκράτορα
>       πάντων ὁρατῶν τε καὶ ἀοράτων ποιητήν·
>       καὶ εἰς ἕνα Κύριον Ἰησοῦν Χριστὸν
>       τὸν Υἱὸν τοῦ Θεοῦ,
>       γεννηθέντα ἐκ τοῦ Πατρὸς μονογενῆ
>       τουτέστιν ἐκ τῆς οὐσίας τοῦ Πατρος
>       Θεὸν ἐκ Θεοῦ,
>       Φῶς ἐκ Φωτός,
>       Θεὸν ἀληθινὸν ἐκ Θεοῦ ἀληθινοῦ,
>       γεννηθέντα, οὐ ποιηθέντα,
>       ὁμοούσιον τῷ Πατρί,
>       δι’ οὗ τὰ πάντα ἐγένετο
>       τά τε ἐν τῷ οὐρανῷ καὶ τὰ ἐν τῇ γῇ,
>       τὸν δι’ ἡμᾶς τοὺς ἀνθρώπους, καὶ
>       διὰ τὴν ἡμετέραν σωτηρίαν,
>       κατελθόντα,
>       καὶ σαρκωθέντα,
>       καὶ ἐνανθρωπήσαντα,
>       παθόντα,
>       καὶ ἀναστάντα τῇ τρίτῃ ἡμέρᾳ,
>       ἀνελθόντα εἰς τοὺς οὐρανούς,
>       ἐρχόμενον κρῖναι ζῶντας καὶ νεκρούς.
>       καὶ εἰς τὸ Ἅγιον Πνεῦμα.
>       Τοὺς δὲ λέγοντας Ἦν ποτε ὅτε οὐκ ἦν,
>       καὶ Πρὶν γεννηθῆναι οὐκ ἦν,
>       καὶ ὅτι Ἐξ οὐκ ὄντων εγένετο,
>       ἢ Ἐξ ἑτέρας ὑποστάσεως ἢ οὐσιάς φάσκοντας εἶναι
>       ἢ κτιστόν
>       ἢ τρεπτόν
>       ἢ ἀλλοιωτὸν τὸν Υἱὸν τοῦ Θεοῦ,
>       τούτους ἀναθεματίζει ἡ ἁγία καθολικὴ καὶ ἀποστολικὴ ἐκκλησία.

English translation of the 325 version:

> We believe in one God,
>       the Father almighty,
>       maker of all things visible and invisible;
>       And in one Lord, Jesus Christ,
>       the Son of God,
>       begotten from the Father, only begotten,
>       that is, from the substance of the Father,
>       God from God,
>       light from light,
>       true God from true God,
>       begotten not made,
>       of one substance with the Father,
>       through Whom all things came into being,
>       things in heaven and things on earth,
>       Who because of us men and because of our salvation came down,
>       and became incarnate
>       and became man,
>       and suffered,
>       and rose again on the third day,
>       and ascended to the heavens,
>       and will come to judge the living and dead,
>       And in the Holy Spirit.
>       But as for those who say, There was when He was not,
>       and, Before being born He was not,
>       and that He came into existence out of nothing,
>       or who assert that the Son of God is of a different hypostasis or substance,
>       or created,
>       or is subject to alteration or change. 
>       - these the Catholic and apostolic Church anathematizes.

[Here is comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicene_Creed#Comparison_between_Creed_of_325_and_Creed_of_381) between 352 and 381 versions.

All I could find was [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oaPOnQ5mC8Y) claiming to be in Koine Greek: **ΤΟ ΣΥΜΒΟΛΟΝ ΤΗΣ ΠΙΣΤΕΩΣ (The Symbol of Faith)**

Comment: This question is about the Nicene Creed, I don't think this is the Nicene Creed that you posted.

Comment: @Peter It is, but you're probably more familiar with the 381 revision.